# Entity Framework Core TPH with multiple relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

I have a problem with relation and Discriminator in our database structure. I need to do something like that:

[Table that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCZ3e.png)

| Id | RefId | RefTypeId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Dog | Luke |
| 2 | 2 | Cat | Kratos |
| 3 | 2 | Dog | Panther |
| 4 | 3 | Dog | Follow |

Owner Id - is id from Dog Table or Cat Table and everything depends on field "OwnerTypeId"

```
public abstract class HomeAnimal
{
   public int Age {get; set;}
   public int RefId { get; set; }
}


public class DogAnimal : HomeAnimal
{
   public Dog Dog { get; set; }
}

public class CatAnimal : HomeAnimal
{
   public Cat Cat { get; set; }
}
```

Dog and Cat have other class - base field and else.
In method **OnModelCreating**(ModelBuilder modelBuilder), I've added Discriminator for HomeAnimal like :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<HomeAnimal>()
             .ToTable("HomeAnimals")
             .HasDiscriminator<int?>("RefType")
              HasValue<DogAnimal>((int)RefType.Dog)
             .HasValue<CatAnimal>((int)RefType.Cat);
```

Everything looks ok in snapshot but if I try to add new record to the database then I've got a error about "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint"

What should I do to set multiple relation for RefId in HomeAnimal class?

**EDIT:**
Added dog class, for example

```
public class Dog{
   public string Type {get;set}
   public ICollection<DogAnimal> DogAnimals {get;set;}
}
```

Cat class is the same like dog but with ICollection for CatAnimal. I don't have any configuration for that two classes. I'm testing it in SMSS - try to insert new record with correct ref type. I have a row in Dog and Cat table - it's not problem of wrong data inserted

**EDIT 2:**

```
var newDog = new Dog()
{
   Name = "23",
};
context.Add(newDog);
context.SaveChanges();

var newDogAnimal = new DogAnimal()
{
   Age = 13,
   RefId = newDog.Id,
};

context.Add(newDogAnimal);
context.SaveChanges();
/// Here throw error, after save changes
```

Error from save changes ->

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_HomeAnimal_Cat_OwnerId".The conflict occurred in database "TestDatabase", table "dbo.Cat", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: To get to the bottom of this, we'd need to see: 1) Dog class, 2) Cat class, 3) Any modelBuilder configurations for Dog, Cat, DogAnimal and CatAnimal. 4) The code that populates the entity that you are trying to save.  I suspect that the FK issue is betwen Dog and DogAnimal or Cat and CatAnimal.

Comment: @NeilW Edited post - please check it now

Comment: Still don't see the code trying to insert the entity.  What is the full error.  You mention error 'about" FK constraint.  Can you post the full error?

Comment: @NeilW added code and exception message. I just added new dog to the database and then try to set ownerId by the id from added dog before. Everything should be ok but that Discriminator not working properly - I think that should lookup correct table if I call "DogAnimal"

Comment: *Polymorphic associations* (what essentially are you trying to implement here) as well as any other "logical" relationship which cannot be represented with enforced FK relationship in database are not currently supported.

Comment: @IvanStoev Oh, I don't know about that. For now I just remove foreign keys and RefId is just a field. Works ok